# Missing Schema.org types 'QAPage' and 'Question' for question without answer

Tags: bug, design, unanswered-questions, seo

If a question has no answer, the structured data is missing the Schema.org types `QAPage` and `Question`.

### Example: [question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2224/60) with answer

The `QAPage` item is specified on the `html` element, and the `Question` item is specified on the `div` element:

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage" class="html__responsive">
```

```html
<div itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
```

[What Google’s SDTT parses](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?hl=en#url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoftwarerecs.stackexchange.com%2Fq%2F2224%2F60):

> [image]

### Example: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19135200/1591669) without answer

It has neither the `QAPage` type nor the `Question` type.

The `html` element (which would usually carry the `QAPage` type) doesn’t create any Microdata item, and the `div` element (which would usually carry the `Question` type) has no type specified (only `itemscope`):

```html
<html class="html__responsive">
```

```html
<div itemscope>
```

[What Google’s SDTT parses](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?hl=en#url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fq%2F19135200%2F1591669):

> [image]

As no `itemtype` is specified for the item (that gets created with `itemscope`), no [*vocabulary identifier*](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-microdata-20180426/#dfn-vocabulary-identifier) is prepended to the properties (`name`, `image`, `upvoteCount` etc.).  This means that **these properties aren’t Schema.org properties** (except for the `name` that belongs to the `Person`, as there the Schema.org type is specified).

That’s why the SDTT says "Unspecified Type", and that’s why it prepends the document’s base URL (`https://stackoverflow.com/`) to the properties.

### Recommended fix

It should be fine to use [`QAPage`](https://schema.org/QAPage) and [`Question`](https://schema.org/Question) if no [`Answer`](https://schema.org/Answer) is posted yet. It’s also fine for Google’s [Q&A Page rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/qapage?hl=en):

> The `Question` type defines the question that this page answers, and includes the answers, **if any**, to that question.

> `answerCount` - Integer - The total number of answers to the question. For example, if there are 15 answers, but only the first 10 are marked up due to pagination, this value would be 15. **This may also be 0 for questions with no answers.**

> For questions without answers, set the `answerCount` property to 0.

So, the most straightforward fix would be to use the same structured data (that gets used for a question with answer) for a question without answer. The only difference would be to omit the `suggestedAnswer`/`acceptedAnswer` properties.

(currently, `answerCount: 0` is already provided for a question without answer, as the screenshot above shows)

### Alternative fix

If, for some reason, `QAPage` shouldn’t be used, you could

- either use its parent type [`WebPage`](https://schema.org/WebPage) instead of `QAPage` (and everything else stays the same):

  ```html
  <html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" class="html__responsive">

  <div itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
  ```
- or omit the page type, and just use [`Question`](https://schema.org/Question) (without `mainEntity`):

  ```html
  <html class="html__responsive">

  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
  ```

Comment: [Relevant tweet from Nick Craver](https://twitter.com/nick_craver/status/1080474872663412738)

Comment: @VoteDukakis: Indeed, thank you! -- Currently, the SDTT doesn’t report any error for a `QAPage` with a `Question` without `Answer`. Not sure, though, if this was the case back in January, too (and Google reported the errors via the Search Console only), or if the SDTT got changed in the meantime.